# Windows CE Startmenu edit

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

Hallo I would like to remove some items from the startmenu in a windows ce device.
It should look like 
[image]

I want that the normal user cannot access the settings. He must be able only to switch-off/restart the device.

I tried to edit the registry but without success. Do you know a way how to do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per the start menu source code, we can remove only "Suspend" icon through the registry. You can concentrate on 'WINCE600\PUBLIC\SHELL\OAK\HPC\EXPLORER\TASKBAR\stmenu.cpp'.

Comment: thanks but I have a mobile device with Windows CE and there is no such file on it.

Comment: I thought you are a developer having the host PC and the development environment. We need to modify the start menu source code in the development PC and then create new OS image to load into the device. In the device there is no such option attain your goal.